# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: (help!!!)

Tags: python, installation, pip, lxml

Im trying to install Lxml

Error Message:  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qgxmbfo1\lxml\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qgxmbfo1\lxml\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-365qwxej\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\lxml'
cwd: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qgxmbfo1\lxml
Complete output (74 lines):
Building lxml version 4.5.2.
Building without Cython.
Building against pre-built libxml2 andl libxslt libraries
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
copying src\lxml_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
copying src\lxml_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron
copying src\lxml\isoschematron_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron
copying src\lxml\etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
copying src\lxml\etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes_*init*_.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
running build_ext
building 'lxml.etree' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qgxmbfo1\lxml\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qgxmbfo1\lxml\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-365qwxej\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\lxml' Check the logs for full command output.

I really dont know what to do pls help

Comment: lxml does not yet support Python 3.9. Check this out - https://pypi.org/project/lxml/. Downgrade your Python version and check.

Comment: hey so i need to uninstall python 3.9 and install 3.8 and then it will work?

Comment: Yes. As per https://pypi.org/project/lxml/ it only supported up to 3.8. Check Programming Language section.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday i upgraded to Python 3.9 and the pip install lxml also failed.
But i managers to install it from a downloaded whl file. Can not remember from where i downloaded it, but you should be avle to find the answer somewhere on stackoverflow .
The lxml package installation seems to work fine for me with bs4

Maybe it was from here:
[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

lxml‑4.5.2‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl <---